# Connect three laptops without using wireless?

Tags: networking

I have a situation where I need to have three laptops be able to connect to each other, but it cannot be over wireless ad hoc network.  This has to be a portable situation.  I imagine I'd need a hub or router, but I'm not sure.  Networking isn't my forte.  Basically, all three laptops will be running an application, but the database for the application will only be on one laptop (the other two laptops will connect, somehow, to the "main" laptop in order to access the database).

So, in essence, it's like having a main "parent" laptop that is broadcasting the database to the two child laptops.

Does anyone have any advice on how to go about doing this?  For security reasons, it cannot be a wireless solution.

Comment: You need an Ethernet switch.

Comment: So, all the laptops would plug into this switch?  And then each could "see" the other laptops or, at the least, the "parent" laptop?

Comment: Yes, there is quite a bit about network fundamentals you might need to know. What OS are these laptops running?

Comment: There's quite a bit missing here and agreed you'll need a switch. You'll have to configure the networking as well as how you want them to view each other, either through homegroup or workgroup if it's a Windows platform.

Comment: Windows 7 will be the OS.  We mainly just want all of the laptops to be able to "see" a database that will be hosted on one of the three laptops.  Each laptop will be running an app and can be configured to point to a location where the database is being hosted.

Comment: What technology is the database? MSSQL, MySQL or something else?

Comment: We're looking at using SQL Server Express (with TCP/IP protocols enabled and broadcasting/listening over port 1433)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://lifehacker.com/5883517/how-to-set-up-windows-7-homegroups-for-seamless-instant-sharing-between-pcs-in-your-home](http://Windows%207%20Homegroup)

So first thing you're going to need to setup a homegroup. They're going to have to be configured with IP addresses in the same subnet.

After you setup the homegroup, you should be good to go with the basic network setup.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article!  It'll help get me to where I need to be.